# If I reinstall Windows, can I save or recover my current Wubi install?

Tags: 12.10, wubi, windows-7, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I copy my wubi install between machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56726/can-i-copy-my-wubi-install-between-machines)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using WUBI installer in Windows 8, but now I want to reformat my computer to Windows 7. Is there any way to preserve Ubuntu 12.10 and reformat Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/56726/14916 (this one is when moving wubi to a different machine, but the same principle applies).